# How to convert a function address to a symbol

Tags: windows, debugging, symbols, debug-symbols

Let's say I have a program like this

```
// print-addresses.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() { }

void bar() { }

void moo() { }

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  printf("%p\n", foo);
  printf("%p\n", bar);
  printf("%p\n", moo);
  return 0;
}
```

It prints some numbers like

```
013510F0
013510A0
01351109
```

How do I convert those numbers back into the correct symbols? Effectively I'd like to be able to do this

```
print-addresses > address.txt
addresses-to-symbols < address.txt
```

And have it print

```
foo
bar
moo
```

I know this has something to do with the [Debug Interface Access SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but it's not entirely clear to me how I go from an address to a symbol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems like exactly what you're looking for: [Retrieving Symbol Information by Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This uses DbgHelp.dll and relies on calling [SymFromAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You have to do that (I think) from within the running application, or by reading in a minidump file.

You can also use the DIA, but the calling sequence is a bit more complicated.  Call [IDiaDataSource::loadDataForExe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12kk9t39%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [IDiaDataSource::openSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tw26387%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get an [IDiaSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sy4ebfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), then [IDiaSession::getSymbolsByAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sya9d56a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get [IDiaEnumSymbolsByAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94x451ae%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Then, [IDiaEnumSymbolsByAddr::symbolByAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7dhd2yk6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will let you look up a symbol by address.  There is also a way (shown in the example at the last link) to enumerate all symbols.

**EDIT:** This DIA sample application might be a good starting point for using DIA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd8h6f46%28v=vs.71%29.aspx . Particularly check out the parts using `IDiaEnumSymbolsByAddr`.

You could also parse the output of [dumpbin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429), probably with /SYMBOLS or /DISASM option.

Comment: as far as I can tell none of these solution actually answer the question. I happen to know that data in dumpbin is not enough. Your first answer requires being run in the original program. The middle answer might work but it's not clear.

Comment: @gman: I'm sorry, could you let me know what isn't clear about the middle answer?  The first answer *does* work from outside the program, you just need to generate a minidump file and load it.

Answer (score 1):

if you are in linux, you could try addr2line

```
addr2line addr -e execuablebin -f
```